# How has System.exit() wrt to an ANT build changed in JDK 18?

Tags: java, ant, openjdk-21

```
    <target name="myTask" depends="compile">
        <java classname="Main" >
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${classes.dir}"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
        <echo message="myTask completed"/>
    </target>
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main from Java!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Executing `ant myTask`:

Output with JDK 17

```
     [java] Main from Java!
     [echo] myTask completed
```

Output with JDK 18

```
     [java] Main from Java!
```

The JVM exits with a `System.exit()` in JDK 18 but was not doing so in JDK 17. Is there a  know change introduced in JDK 18 related to this behavior?

Comment: Of course not. This is about `ant`, not Java.

Comment: running that with 17 I got the following warnings (missing in question, and *probably* explaining the problem): "WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.apache.tools.ant.types.Permissions (file:/C:/Program%20Files/Ant-1.10/lib/ant.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.tools.ant.types.Permissions
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release" - the `SecurityManager` *can* be used to inhibit the execution of `System.exit()`

Comment: @user85421 Wouldn't the OP see a `SecurityException` if a security manager was blocking the call to `exit`?

Comment: @Slaw no, they cannot see it - the exception is probably being `catch`ed and ignored (at least `exit()` is not stopping the JVM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Ant updated its behavior from v 1.10.14 due to SecurityManager's removal in JDK 18.

> when using Java 18 or higher, if the build executes
> tasks that call "java.lang.System.exit()" and if those tasks aren't
> running in a forked VM of their own, then such tasks will now kill
> the entire Ant build process.

Source: https://downloads.apache.org/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.10.14.html